# TinyMCE - Tabbing to editor causes cursor to right align? FF4 problem maybe?

Tags: tabs, tinymce, firefox4, cursor-position

When I view my site in Firefox 4, if I tab to the tinyMCE editor, it right aligns the cursor, when I begin typing it adds an empty line to the top and then the typing begins left-aligned on the next line.  This doesn't happen in IE8 and I'm not sure if it happens in an earlier version of FF because I'm not sure how to install simultaneous versions of the same program.  Has anyone else encountered this?  Is this specific to the buggy FF4?  Is there a way to hack around it?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install several instances of Firefox on any OS. To identify the problem i suggest you install the "old" FF 3.6 in another location as the other.

Comment: you can't get users to do this

Comment: why not? i see no problem with this

Comment: put simply, because users, upon seeing a message "Please downgrade your browser for this web site", will ignore it. Or leave the website. They won't actually do it. ~20% of web users are still on IE6.

Comment: i do not understand the problem here, we are not talking about users, but about linus72982 who is the single person here to install the old FF in order to find out if his problem is a FF related thing or not!